# Expresso - Store : How to create a "Notify me when product is available" when product is out of stock

Tags: expresso-store, module, email, out-of-stock

Is there a plugin or method to create a "Notify me when product is available" when a product is out of stock? I will like to let the CMS send an email to users who opt in to the notification whenever the project stock is replenished.

Regards,
Rin

Comment: Rin, drop me an email peter@peteralewis.com and I'll send you a beta version of a Stock Alert module I'm working on.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the offer. My client has currently placed this on the back burner, so I'll just add in a 'Out of stock' comment for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Store directly that would allow you to send an email based upon the stock changing. I would recommend you use a conditional in your template similar to

```
{if total_stock == 0}
 // Signup form to collect
 // users email address
 // goes here
{/if}
```

Depending on which approach you use for collecting the users email address you can send an email to them letting them know that the item is back in stock. Some things you will need to think about is unsubscribing users from the list after the email is sent or do you want to leave them in the list unless they unsubscribe.

To automate the process of sending out an email you could write an extension based upon one of the extension hooks. I would probably say the [store_inventory_datatable](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/extension_hooks.html#store_inventory_datatable) would fit your needs.

Comment: Surely the store_inventory_datatable (for modifying within the Store module listing) and entry_submission_absolute_end hooks (for modifying via normal entry)?

Comment: Yea that sounds like what I would do.